# Downloading Gmail Credentials.json File

Tags: asp.net-identity, gmail-api

Good day!

My goal is to send email messages through ASP.NET Identity using Gmail.  Now, in the tutorial from Google, shown below, it states that I should "Drag credentials.json, downloaded as a prerequisite, into your Visual Studio Solution Explorer."  I would like to know how to how to download the credentials.json file as discussed in the tutorial.

[image]

Here is my credentials page from Google:
[image]

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you create an OAuth 2.0 Client ID there is an option to download the JSON file:

[image]

If you missed it, simply click on the download icon under `Actions`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response.  In my case, I found a tab at the top of the page that was labeled "Download JSON".